# Why does mpl's pyplot refuse to auto format x-axis when I use the datestr2num conversion?

Tags: csv, matplotlib

Been playing around with this for a while. I'm reading data from a csv and trying to plot a timestamp on the x-axis. In order to plot my timestamp, I have to convert it to something other than a string (afaik). All my attempts to autoformat the x-axis to fit the data range have failed. Its giving me +/- about 2 years on my axis for data that spans hours. Im not dead set on datestr2num either, just trying to figure out how to accomplish all this with csv.reader

```
import csv 
import time
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime 
import matplotlib.dates as dates

filename = ''  #csv goes here
callback = ''
global counter
results =''
counter = 0
timestr = []
thickness = []

def csv_process(filename, callback, delay=1): 
    class waiter:     
        def __init__(self, fd, delay=1):
            self.fd = fd
            self.delay = delay
        def __iter__(self):
            return self
        def next(self): 
            while True:
                line = fd.readline()
                if line:
                    return line
                time.sleep(self.delay)
                results()
        def __next__(self):  # bc im using Python3.4
            return self.next()
    with open(filename, "r") as fd:
        rows = csv.reader(waiter(fd, delay), delimiter=',')
        for row in rows:
            rows.__next__()
            callback(row)
        results()

def process_row(row):
    global thickness, counter, timestr 
    counter = counter+1
    if counter > 6:    #csv file has 5 lines of header data
        timestr = matplotlib.dates.datestr2num(row[0])
        thickness.append(row[3])
        return thickness, timestr

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
line, = plt.plot_date([], [], '.')
plt.ion()

def results():
    global line
    line.set_data(timestr, thickness)
    plt.show()
    while 1: 
        plt.draw()
        ax.relim()
        ax.autoscale_view(True,True,True)
        plt.pause(.001)
        return line

 if __name__ == "__main__":
    csv_process(filename, process_row)
```

Sample of my timestamp:

```
2015-08-19 11:18:46.700000
2015-08-19 11:18:48.950000
```

Comment: Can you simplify this code at all?  There are a lot of moving parts, most of which are unrelated to the problem you are having. (also, why do you have an infinite loop with a return inside of it?).

Comment: I'm trying to plot real time data as its being measured, so I just looped it to keep checking for new data. I personally believe the source of the problem is my conversion of the timestamp string using datestr2num.

Comment: I would go to datetime objects and let mpl take care of the conversions.  With your current example there is not much more advice i can offer.  If you get it down to a ten line example it would be a lot easier.

Comment: I just tested converting timestr to a datetime object and its behaving the exact same way. My x axis is showing from Aug 2013 to Aug to 2017. I also tried to append timestr and remove YMD altogether but I get an error saying datetime object not subscriptable..